# How to run command as a different user when there are no sudo or su commands

Tags: command-line, su

I have this quite unusual condition here. I have a old linux system that has no sudo or su commands. I do not have physical access to this computer so I cannot login as another user.

Linux kernel is 2.6.18-498 and the system is a red-hat 4.1.2-55.

I can go to the /bin directory and can say for sure there are no su or sudo binaries there. So this is not the case of PATH variables misconfigaration.

Also this is a web server so maybe it is configured this way. Is there any way to run a command as a different user? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sudo` may be in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: `find / -name 'su*' -print`

Comment: The su is not present in the  /usr/bin either. find / -name "su*" does not give the location of su just some gibberish files. I am pretty sure su is not present

Comment: `find / -executable -type f -name 'su*' -print 2>/dev/null` will give a more concise list: no directories, and only executables.

Comment: Okay I executed the find with the given options and still there is no su binary anywere. I strongly think there is no binary su here.

Comment: What is the system?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor uname -s returns Linux . I hope that is what you are asking for

Comment: You seem to be able to login remotely, is this correct? Can you run `login` once logged in?

Comment: Yup the problem is that the terminal is not interactive. The remote login just gives you a place to enter commands and outputs the output of the command. So I suppose login will not work. Though I am able to run login.

Comment: No Linux is a component. What is the system? System: a set of things working together as parts of a mechanism or an interconnecting network; a complex whole; **A group of related hardware units or programs or both, especially when dedicated to a single application.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you have any remote login services running (`in.telnetd`, `rlogind`, `sshd`) and then run the appropriate login command to the localhost (127.0.0.1).  For example if you have `sshd` then do:

```
$ ssh root@127.0.0.1
```

With `telnet` you'd run:

```
$ telnet -l root 127.0.0.1
```

And with `rlogin` you'd run:

```
$ rlogin -l root 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This worked for me sshd works. Thank you. I didn't think of services running. Stupid me!

Answer (score 2):

Any command with set-uid, or set gid-bit, set. Will be run as the owning user or group. However if they are written properly, they will not let you do anything that you should not. `sudo` and `su` only allow you to do anything of significance if you provide the correct password. Most other tools will just do one thing safely, but not allow you to escalate privileges.

However if you can write to the storage, as root (by removing media, and inserting into another machine, or booting into a different OS), then you can add the files that you need, with the appropriate permission.

Executables with set-uid/set-gid bits, are the **only** way of escalating privilege in Unix systems (The modern systems now have capabilities, but these amount to the same thing).

The kernel does not use passwords, so to implement passwords, an executable with root owner and set-uid bit set, is created. This executable will check the password, and then set the user appropriately, and start a shell (or something).

Supposing there is no use of capabilities, then `find / -executable -type f -user root -perm -u+s -print 2>/dev/null` will list all executables that elevate permission (at least temporarily), most (maybe all) will be useless.

Comment: I have the root password. I just need a way to change to the root user.

Comment: I am pretty familiar with suid bits. I can assure you that there is no privilege escalation executables here. (I think there should not be any for security reason anyway) Searching for files with suid bit either returns files which I myself am the owner of (so no use) or lists the directories I do not have permissions to view.